# Enable AVX intrinsics in GCC 4.8.2 without -mavx

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there anyways to get the AVX intrinsics included via x86intrin.h in GCC 4.8.2 without turning on -mavx for the whole compilation unit?  I only want to *use* them in a function that I've marked target("avx").  More recent versions of gcc seem to do this correctly.   But with 4.8.2 even if I manually `#define __AVX__` (ew), it complains about the __builtin* functions not being defined...

Comment: Can you just compile this function in its own compilation unit?

Comment: I'd prefer not to if I can avoid it

Comment: You write only that function in assembly if it is small enough, then you don't need `x86intrin.h` file only.

Comment: @yadhu Yeah thought about that but I'm probably going to have several intrinsic functions and don't want to have to inline the assembly for all of them.  I think I'm screwed, which is disappointing because Intel and more recent GCC versions let you do this.